Error "malformed range literal" when loading a CSV file with pgAdmin 4
I am new to running pgAdmin 4, and have been getting the following error message when attempting to load a CSV file into my table:
ERROR: malformed range literal: "2023-08-01 00-00"
DETAIL: Missing left parenthesis or bracket.
CONTEXT: COPY aug2023_trip, line 2, column started_at: "2023-08-01 00-00"

This is the CREATE TABLE Statement:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.aug2023_trip
(
    ride_id character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    rieable_type character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    started_at tsrange,
    ended_at tsrange,
    ride_length time without time zone,
    day_of_week smallint,
    start_station_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    start_staion_id character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    end_station_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    end_station_id character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    start_lat numeric,
    start_lng numeric,
    end_lat numeric,
    end_lng numeric,
    member_casual character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.aug2023_trip
    OWNER to postgres;

I ran a test without the started_at, ended_at, and ride_length columns, and the data loaded into the database.
So the error is with the column data types of started_at, ended_at, and ride-length.
Can anyone provide a hint to why I am getting this error message?

A constant of type tsrange should look like this:
[2023-08-01 00:00:00,2023-08-01 12:00:00)

I think that the real problem is that you chose the wrong data types.

based on the name and the constant in the error message, I'd say that started_at and ended_at should be timestamp with time zone, or that you store both in a single column start_end of type tstzrange (but you'd have to change the CSV file for the latter).

ride_length should be an interval, but if that is just ended_at - started_at, you should not store that (redundant) information at all, since you can always calculate it on the fly.



Hell Laurenz, appreciate the feedback.  The timestamp data type worked for the started_at and ended_at columns.  The interval data type did not work for the ride_length, so I'm looking for a work around.

"Did not work" is always an inadequate problem description.
